# How to get column properties in Doctrine custom type convertToDatabaseValue function?

Tags: php, doctrine

As the title suggests, I am making my own `Type` in Doctrine and the type has its `precision` and `scale` options in `getSQLDeclaration()` function. I need somehow to access these from `convertToDatabaseValue()` as well, as I need to round the number with given precision.

```php
<?php

namespace App\DBAL\Types;

use Decimal\Decimal;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DecimalType as DoctrineDecimalType;

class DecimalType extends DoctrineDecimalType
{
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $column, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
    {
        $column['precision'] = empty($column['precision'])
            ? 10 : $column['precision'];
        $column['scale']     = empty($column['scale'])
            ? 0 : $column['scale'];

        return 'DECIMAL(' . $column['precision'] . ', ' . $column['scale'] . ')' .
            (!empty($column['unsigned']) ? ' UNSIGNED' : '');
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            return null;
        }

        return new Decimal($value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value instanceof Decimal) {
            // HERE!! This is the line where I need to specify precision based on column declaration
            return $value->toFixed(????);
        }

        return parent::convertToDatabaseValue($value, $platform); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

So the Entity column then looks like:

```php
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'decimal', precision: 10, scale: 4)]
    private Decimal $subtotal;
```

And I need to get the `scale` or `precision` part in the `convertToDatabaseValue()` function.

Comment: You are inverting the way Doctrine uses the ORM and DBAL portions of the `ORM\Column::$type` definition. The `ORM\Column` is explicitly for schema purposes only, which the ORM utilizes the DBAL `type` reference(s) you specify in the ORM config.  While the DBAL `type` portion only functions to transform the data-type to/from PHP and the database. As such the `ORM\Column` settings cannot become available in either `convertTo[PHP|Database]Value` methods, since they would be unavailable to the DBAL. You would need to setup an `EventListener` to function as a Transformer.

Comment: But sometimes converting to Database value does require the underlying column details, such as in my case the precision, or e.g. whether the field is unsigned. Can you please elaborate on your EventListener idea? Thanks

Comment: You're confusing value formatting and data-type schema. `ORM\Column` is only defining the data-type schema the value *is*, not what the value should be converted to if it doesn't match the schema. In practice the Entity itself should deal with formatting the supplied value before executing any SQL, just as you would when manually writing a native query. Otherwise you break consistency/relationships between them.  IE a `SIGNED` vs `UNSIGNED` ID value. Parsing the schema specifications to format every column value for every Entity would be an enormous amount of overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, what you're attempting to do is not supported. While there are methods of forcing a similar type of functionality, such as with lifecycle callbacks, they are considered [extremely bad-practice](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/58) as they point towards persistence issues.

The general principal is that Entities should work **without** relying on either the ORM or the Database layers, and implementing workarounds to force the behavior may result in breaks in your application.

In practice the value being supplied to the Entity should be formatted as desired based on the schema rules, exactly as one would when supplying values to a native SQL query.

This ensures the integrity and consistency of the Entity data is maintained throughout the application and the underlying data that each Entity holds is **always valid**, without requiring the ORM or database layers to *"fix"* the data.

```
$decimal = new Decimal('1337.987654321');
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setSubtotal($decimal->toFixed(4));

echo $entity->getSubtotal(); // 1337.9876
```

In contrast to the example above, when relying on the ORM or database layer, the data would be **invalid** until after `$em->flush();` was called to *"fix"* the value format based on the ORM specifications and calling `convertToDatabaseValue()`. Whereby calling `$entity->getSubtotal();` prior to `$em->flush()` would instead return `1337.987654321` which does not conform to the column specifications, causing business logic relying on the value to become broken.

### Object Casting Example

Since you are relying on a separate library package that is not suitable to modify or to switch to a custom object.

Another approach is to utilize the default [Doctrine `decimal` type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#decimal-types) specifications which works on `string` data-type values and utilizing casting within the Entity instead. Circumventing the need for a custom `DecimalType` or workarounds and the entity would more easily be applicable to the rest of the Symfony framework without the need for additional workarounds.

**[3V4L Example](https://3v4l.org/D4LDE#v8.0.17)**

```
class Entity
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'decimal', precision: 10, scale: 4)]
    private string $subtotal = '0.0';

    // name as desired
    public function getSubtotalDecimal(): Decimal
    {
        return new Decimal($this->subtotal);
    }

    public function getSubtotal(): string
    {
        return $this->subtotal;
    }

    // see Union Types
    public function setSubtotal(string|Decimal $subtotal): self
    {
        if ($subtotal instanceof Decimal) {
            $subtotal = $subtotal->toFixed(4);
        }
        $this->subtotal = $subtotal;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setSubtotal(new Decimal('1337.987654321'));

echo $entity->getSubtotal(); // 1337.9876
echo $entity->getSubtotalDecimal()->toFixed(4); // 1337.9876
```

It is [recommended to use a DTO](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/) (data-transfer object) to perform validation and formatting of the data prior to being applied to the Entity (see DTO Example below).

---

### DTO Example

Basic usage of Symfony generally allows for manipulation of the entities directly, such as when using Forms and `EntityType` fields. However, with the principal that the Entities are **always valid**, there should not be a need to validate the Entity data that was injected into it by the Form containing user-supplied data.

To prevent invalid data within the Entity and promote separations of concerns, a DTO can be used to structure the data based on the immediate concerns for what that data is being used for.

To make DTOs easier to utilize, the Doctrine ORM supports the [generation of DTOs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax), which can be used as the model in Forms.

It is also important to note that Doctrine has deprecated [`partial` objects](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/partial-objects.html) support in the future in favor of using a DTO for partial objects [[sic]](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/8472).

```
class OrderSubtotalDTO
{
    private string $company;
    private string $subtotal;

    public function __construct(string $company, string $subtotal)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
        $this->subtotal = $subtotal;
    }

     // ...

    public function setSubtotal(string $value): self
    {
        $this->subtotal = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function apply(Entity $entity): self
    {
        // apply the formatting being supplied to the entity
        $entity->setSubtotal(new Decimal($this->subtotal)->toFixed(4));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
// use a Query service to reduce code duplication - this is for demonstration only
$q = $em->createQuery('SELECT NEW OrderSubtotalDTO(e.company, e.subtotal) FROM Entity e WHERE e.id = ?1');
$q->setParameter(1, $entity->getId());
$orderSubtotalDTO = $q->getOneOrNull();

$form = $formFactory->create(OrderSubtotalForm::class, $orderSubtotalDTO);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $orderSubtotalDTO->apply($entity);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I feel like my case does NOT break any good practice. Of course, I make sure that the subtotal I set on my entity is rounded only to N decimal places. I do not expect the persisting of entity to "fix" my data as you say. The thing is that the Decimal type can be converted to string ONLY if I provide it exactly the number of decimal places I want. And even tho I make sure subtotal is rounded to 2 decimal places before setting it on entity, when I need to get the value for SQL from convertToDatabaseValue, I need to call toFixed(N).This N I cannot deduce. As a hack, I now use N=28.

Comment: Then it appears the issue is with the `Decimal` object rather than `DecimalType`. Relying on invalid data being used throughout the application is bad-practice. 
Persistence is related to the fact that unless you call `$em->flush()` where `convertToDatabaseValue()` is applied, the data cannot maintain validity throughout the entirety of your application. `convertToDatabaseValue()` should not be required to apply a hack or to fix the value being sent to the database, since `$em->flush()` should not be needed for the data within the Entity being sent to the database to already be valid.

Comment: I disagree, there is no way for me to pass this even if it were custom object. The only solution is to create multiple types then like decimal-10-2, decimal-10-4. As if I have just Decimal, then there is one generic instance used by Doctrine to do the conversion between DB and PHP values. And again, the data in the Decimal type IS valid. It is only when converting from DB value to know how many significant places it will use (due to memory optimization - i.e. the "precision" field) and when converting to DB value (string) how many decimal places to use.

Comment: My point is that the application can not parse the `ORM\Column` annotation/attribute every time you utilize the `Decimal` object. When converting the `Decimal` object to a string to be supplied to the database, the object being supplied to the Entity should already contain all of the necessary information, such as in the case of a `DateTime` object. Updated answer to include an Object Specification Formatting example.

Comment: Ok Will, I see your point. So this aside, what would you suggest I do? I am using php-decimal extension and need to keep using that. I cannot extend the Decimal class to support passing of scale and precision. It seems that I am stuck with either making the decimal-10-2 solution or using toFixed(28) which will result in lot of trailing zeros in actual SQL, but DB will just ignore them and itll work fine. Your thoughts?

Comment: Yea, trying to get a square peg to fit into a round hole doesn't workout in the long run. In this instance, I would recommend relying on the default Doctrine `decimal` type configuration and use casting within your Entity get/set methods to produce the desired results. I updated the answer with another Object Casting Example. It is an approach I have used due to other devs creating improper `DATETIME` column schema type specifications as `string`, in order to force `DateTimeInterface` objects.

Comment: Yes, thats what I was using, but it does not resolve the issue that in one place, the convertToDatabaseValue should return 2 decimal places, on other it should be 4. toFixed() gives you string, not a Decimal. Decimal does not save "scale". So no matter how I process and set it inside Entity setter, at convertToDatabaseValue I have no idea what toFixed(N) I should use. So I need to hardcode N to be big enough to not truncate any date, basically the biggest scale I plan to use in all of the Decimal types across my project.

Comment: I'd need to see an example of your Entity or Entities and how you are using `Decimal` in the context of the scale to give more advice, some of the context was missing from the question. From what it appears is that you need a separate setter for applying the desired scale to the `Decimal` value. Which is the same issue with handling [`DATETIME` with time zones](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html#handling-different-timezones-with-the-datetime-type) with the ORM.